# Creating A Process Queue in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I have a server running Hunchentoot (CentOS and SBCL). When a user submits a specific type of post request, a subprocess is launched (run-program) which can take up to four minutes to complete. If five people perform that specific type of request at the same time, the server runs out of memory and all of the subprocesses break. What technique do you recommend for queueing up the processes and running them one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a single worker thread which receives instructions from a message queue.  I have used `chanl` in the past for similar things, but there are several other options.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(defvar *worker-queue* '())
(defvar *worker-queue-mutex* (sb-thread:make-mutex :name "worker-queue-lock"))
(defvar *worker-queue-semaphore* (sb-thread:make-semaphore :name "worker-queue-semaphore" :count 0))
(defvar *worker-thread*)

(defun worker-queue-function ()
  (sb-thread:with-mutex (*worker-queue-mutex*)
    (let ((popped-worker-queue-item (pop *worker-queue*)))
      (do-something-with popped-worker-queue-item))))

(defun make-worker-thread ()
  (setq *worker-thread* (sb-thread:make-thread (lambda ()
        (loop
          (sb-thread:wait-on-semaphore *worker-queue-semaphore*)
          (worker-queue-function)))
        :name "worker-thread")))

(defun add-item-to-worker-queue (item-to-add-to-worker-queue)
  (sb-thread:with-mutex (*worker-queue-mutex*)
    (setq *worker-queue* (append *worker-queue* (list item-to-add-to-worker-queue)))
    (sb-thread:signal-semaphore *worker-queue-semaphore*))))
```

Comment: Note: This is SBCL specific.

Comment: Well, why not use a portable library that also simplifies semantics for you?

Comment: I looked at [Bordeaux Threads](https://common-lisp.net/project/bordeaux-threads/), but I had a working example in the [Lisp Koans](https://github.com/google/lisp-koans), so I ran with that.

Comment: What I have seen of those koans does not inspire trust into their general usefulness.